# AWS Amplify Storage | Upload large file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

Using AWS Amplify Storage, uploading a file to AWS S3 should be simple:

```
Storage.put(key, blob, options)
```

The above works without problem for **smaller files**, (no larger than around 4MB).

Uploading anything larger, ex. a 25MB video, does not work: `Storage` just freezes (app does not freeze, only `Storage`). No error is returned.

**Question:** How can I upload larger files using AWS Amplify Storage?

Side note: Described behaviour appears both on Android and iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Amplify now automatically segments large files into 5Mb chunks and uploads them using the Amazon S3 Multipart upload process

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/10/aws-amplify-javascript-file-uploads-storage/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpuoverview.html#mpu-process

Comment: Looks like another 'hidden' AWS Amplify bug. So, what is the proper answer? Migrate to newer Amplify version?

Comment: I have tested files over 100mb with the latest version of Amplify (7.6.5 at the moment of this writing) and it's working without any issues

Comment: "When we used the older version of aws-amplify": "^3.1.1", the problems like you mentioned (author of the question) were present."

Answer (score 1):

After updating to

```
"aws-amplify": "ˆ4.3.11",
"aws-amplify-react-native": "^6.0.2"
```

uploads over 100MB are not freezing UI anymore + we also migrated to [resumable uploads](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/upload/q/platform/js/#pause-and-resume-uploads). When we used older version of aws-amplify": "^3.1.1", the problems like you mentioned were present.

Here is the pull request from Dec, 2021 for mentioned fixes:
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/pull/8336

So the solution is really to upgrade AWS Amplify library.

However, this approach works only on **iOS**.
Uploading big media files **on Android** results in network error when calling fetch (as a required step before calling Storage.put method).

Although the same method can perfectly work on the web, in React Native uploading big files was/is not implemented optimally (taking in mind, that we should load all file in memory using fetch()).