# React Native Expo chunk file and send to S3

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, expo

My main goal is to upload a large video file from the user's phone to s3.

In the past, for a web app, I was able to chunk the user's video selection and upload it to s3 in parts with presigned urls.

What is the best way to upload a large video file the fastest on RN Expo? It doesn't seem like I can chunk the local video files. Things I have tried that didn't work:

1. `const fileStream = await fetch(uri);`  -- results in a failed network request
2. `const fileData = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(uri, { encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64 });` -- fails due to memory issue
3. `{ S3Client, S3 } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3"` -- these AWS libraries seem to be built for web and not RN. Fails due to missing dependencies (buffer, utils, http2, http -- yes I tried to npm install them)

How are apps like IG and Tiktok handling uploading videos from the phone? Is this a RN Expo limitation?

Comment: Take a look at Amplify: https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/upload/q/platform/react-native/.

Comment: @user18309290 yeah seems like the post here, it works for them (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67903859/aws-amplify-storage-upload-large-file). I'll give it a look, thanks

Comment: @user2465134 did you found any solution? can you share here

Comment: @YuvrajChaudhari yes, do you still need a solution?

Comment: @YuvrajChaudhari posted it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a rough outline of what I did that worked:

```
  const uploadVideos = async () => {
    if (!videoUri && !imageUri) {
      return
    }

    setLoading(true)
    const { uri } = videoData
    const CHUNK_SIZE = 5 * 1024 * 1024

    const fileInfo = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(uri)
    const fileSize = fileInfo.size
    
    const partSize = Math.min(CHUNK_SIZE, fileSize)
    const parts = Math.ceil(fileSize / partSize)
    const { signedUrlsDict, videoId, uploadId } = await createVideoPresignedUrl(parts)
  
    let position = 0
    let partsComplete = 0
    const promises = []
  
    while (position < fileSize) {
      const length = Math.min(CHUNK_SIZE, fileSize - partsComplete)
      const chunk = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(uri, {
        encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
        length,
        position,
      })
  
      const binaryData = Buffer.from(chunk, 'base64').buffer
  
      promises.push(
        fetch(signedUrlsDict[position / CHUNK_SIZE], {
          method: 'PUT',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
          },
          body: binaryData,
        })
      )
  
      position += CHUNK_SIZE
      partsComplete += length

      const currentPercent = Math.ceil(position / fileSize * 100)
      if (currentPercent < 100) {
        setProgressMessage(`Video is ${currentPercent}% complete`)
      } else {
        setProgressMessage('Finalizing upload..')
      }
    }
  
    const resParts = await Promise.all(promises)
    const eTags = resParts.map((res, index) => {
      return {
        ETag: res.headers.get('etag'),
        PartNumber: index + 1,
      }
    })
  
    await completeUpload(eTags, uploadId, videoId)
    setProgressMessage('Uploading thumbail.. ')

    uploadThumbnail(videoId)
  }
```

Creating presigned urls:

```
    const { parts } = req.body

    const videoId = uuidv4()

    const params = {
      Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: videoId,
      ContentType: 'video/mp4'
    }

    try {
      const command = new CreateMultipartUploadCommand(params)
      const { UploadId } = await s3Client.send(command)

      const promises = []

      for (let index = 0; index < parts; index++) {
        const command = new UploadPartCommand({
          ...params,
          UploadId,
          PartNumber: index + 1
        })
        const signedPromise = getSignedUrl(s3Client, command, {
          expiresIn: expirationTime
        })
        promises.push(signedPromise)
      }
    
      const resPromises = await Promise.all(promises)
      const signedUrlsDict = {}
      resPromises.forEach((url, i) => {
        signedUrlsDict[i] = url
      })

      return res.status(200).send({
        signedUrlsDict,
        videoId,
        uploadId: UploadId
      })
```

When the video was finished uploading, you had to run the `CompleteCommand` on the BE.

```
    const { parts, uploadId, videoId } = req.body
    
    const params = {
      Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: videoId,
      MultipartUpload: {
        Parts: parts
      },
      UploadId: uploadId
    }


    try {
      const command = new CompleteMultipartUploadCommand(params)

      await s3Client.send(command)
    }
```

Again, don't copy and paste this. It's not 100% separated from my app but it's 99% of the way there. Hope this helps someone.